# Best way for two Spring WebFlow projects to share data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am trying to find the best way for two Spring WebFlow projects to share data. In my example lets say Web-Flow App1 gets information from the user like name, phone, ssn, etc etc and I am going to need to pass control to a diff Web-Flow app lets call it App2 that needs phone and ssn to start.

We can't save the phone and ssn into a database due to some rules so I would like to hear from some other programmers on some of the best ways to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

If the two web-flows actually reside in the same Java web application, simply use a subflow-state from the app1 flow to launch the app2 flow and pass along the required input:

```
<subflow-state id="launchApp2" subflow="app2-flow">
    <input name="phone" />
    <input name="ssn" />
    <transition to="resumeApp1" />
</subflow-state>
```

This is also described in the reference documentation:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch03s09.html

Answer (score 0):

One web app has to pass control to another web app? You coud redirect to http://[app2]/start?phone=123&ssn=456

Comment: The issue is that we don't want to have it as Params so users can see them

Comment: Are they different web apps? You still have a lot of options: cookies, POST. Many (all?) servlet containers have some support for sharing a user session between applications.

Answer (score 0):

Post a form with hidden variables to the other site.

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('theForm').submit();">
<form id="theForm" action="http://app2/..." method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Joe"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="ssn" value="XYZ123..."></input>
...
</form>
</body>
```